# Import doc and docx files in .Net and C#

Tags: .net, ms-word, ms-office

I'm writing a text editor and I want to add the possibility to import .doc and .docx files. I know that I could use OLE Automation, but if I use a recent OLE library, it won't work with those people with an older version of Word, and if instead I use an older version, it won't be able to read .docx files.
Any ideas?
Thanks

EDIT: Another solution would be that, like my application works with HTML and RTF, convert .doc and .docx files with command line to one of these formats, something like this: http://www.snee.com/bobdc.blog/ 2007/09/using-word-for-command-line-co.html

Comment: I hope the text editor your building is a winform app? We wouldn't want you to run into a server-side problem: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Comment: yes, it's a windows forms application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's works with the Office 2003 PIA, tested in my computer running Office 2010:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

public string GetHtmlFromDoc(string path)
    var wordApp = new Application {Visible = false};

//Cargar documento
            object srcPath = path;
            var wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref srcPath);

            //Guardarlo en HTML
            string destPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "word" + (new Random().Next()) + ".html");
            if (wordDoc != null)
            {
                object oDestPath = destPath;
                object exportFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatHTML;
                wordDoc.SaveAs(ref oDestPath, ref exportFormat);
            }

            //Cerrar
            wordDoc.Close();
            wordApp.Quit();

            //Comprobar que el archivo existe);
            if (File.Exists(destPath))
            {
               return File.ReadAllText(destPath, Encoding.Default);
}
return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the [Office Primary Interop Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57(v=VS.100).aspx) (PIAs)?

I think you will have to decide which versions of Word you want to support. I suggest you settle on Word 2003 as the lowest. That will allow you to use the Office 2003 PIAs and program against them. Installing PIAs in a machine installs binding redirects as well, so they work with newer versions on Word. There should be no problem in opening .docx files with Word 2007 or 2010 through Office 2003 PIAs, although I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: Because, as I said, depending on which version of these libraries I use, requires that users have a version of Word same or newer that the version of the library.

Comment: I thought you were talking about OLE Automation. Anyway, I am editing my answer to sketch a solution to the version problem. :-)

Comment: One solution would be to include ALL the OLE Automation libraries so far: P

Comment: I'm agree with you, Office 2003 should be the lowest. But surely it must be installed the compatibility pack to work with .docx

Comment: No, because you won't be opening .docx with Word 2003. Computers with Office 2003 will only open .doc in 2003 format, and computers with Office 2007 will be able to open .doc and .docx. Everything will be done through the Office 2003 PIAs, though.

Comment: This is pretty easy to do and you're on the right track. grab the PIA (or construct your own) from the +earliest+ version of word you need to support (I did a commercial addin a while back that targeted everything from Office 2000 to 2010). Reference THOSE PIA's in your app, and, for any functionality that's NOT defined in those PIAs use latebinding or reflection for access (for instance, the Ribbon, or smarttags). Doing that allows you to support any version of Office (at least as far back as 2000, before that, the COM support was quite different and incompatible).

Comment: @drventure: Exactly; that is what I was trying to explain.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the OpenXML libraries or xpath in .NET to read / import the contents of a docx file.

Comment: good reply, I think the OP is looking more for a Word version neutral approach.. like "Late Binding" for more certain  version-independence.

Comment: I need something more basic, convert word files to html would be sufficient